# Isolated Dc Dc comverter OCP triggers Output OVP on another converter with their inputs connected in parallel and common output ground

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, over-voltage-protection, isolated

In a system we have a bank of isolated dc dc converters that feed a bank of bldc motors with their respective ESCs. These converters have their input connected in parallel to another identical one's input, that's dedicated to control electronics which only consume 1.6% of its output capacity, the control electronics share a ground with the power electronics for signal reference. When the bldc motors draw a large enough trandient to trigger the OCP of their converters, the separate converter for the control electronics has its OVP trigger on the output/secondary side. I'm looking for a decent explanination as to what is happening and possible solutions.

I don't mind the OCP triggering, transients can be limited in software but the OVP reboots the control electronics which takes a long time to recover.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation: when the motors take too much current and their power supply shuts down, there might be a back emf on the main power due to that sudden fall in current and inductive line properties. This would/could affect the electronics power supply and cause a brief over voltage on the input that finds its way to the output and causes the OVP to shut down the converter.

Bad wiring schemes, bad earths, poor regulation on the main power source can also contribute.